# How to create SharePoint provider-hosted-apps without Windows PowerShell

Tags: development, powershell, sharepoint-addin

I already had create SharePoint provider-hosted-apps.
But with Windows PowerShell there was an error and all SharePoint services was changed so I need to create SharePoint provider-hosted-apps without using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Create apps using VS follow the link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can create apps in Visual Studio, I never use Powershell to create apps.

link: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142381.aspx)

Comment: Give me Steps links.